# How to show formula result in messageBox?

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have this formula in crystal report with Visual
Studio 2010. Formula Name is Net.

The formula for calculation  so
the formula is a calculation number I want to show formula result in
message Box or text Box windows forms:

```
({DTCustomerStatement.StartBal}+{#SUMSalesGrand})-({#SUMDof3at}+{#SUMReSalesGrand})
```

How can I do this please?

Comment: calculate and show in messagebox like this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/aa984357(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: not work with formula

Comment: i cant show crystal report  formula result in messagebox